# I am trying to use 2 of the same INNER JOIN function but i cant get it to work

Tags: mysql

This SQL code i use to retrieve flights That fly only within one area which is AK

Table airports contains AirportID, AirportDetail

table flights contains FlightNum, TakeOff, ArriveID

```
SELECT DISTINCT FlightNum, TakeOffID, ArriveID
FROM flights
INNER JOIN airports
 ON AirportID = ArriveID AND AirportID = TakeOffID
WHERE AirportDetail LIKE '%AK%'
```

Comment: Don't you need `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Add some sample data to the post from both tables along with expected result.  it will help us understand your problem.  the "can't get it to work" is too vague.  Is there an error?  what are you getting? what do you expect to get?  do you need two inner joins; one for destination and one for origin?

Comment: So you want flights that depart from and return to the same airport AK?

Comment: If you're joining on the airport ID, it will only fetch results where the airplane departs from and returns to the same *AirportID*. If you want to get results based on the airport's *state* you need to join on that, not the airport ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xQbert's answer is close, but it might not be clear to you why. Here is a way of doing it without joins that might help you understand better how to think about the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM flight
WHERE DestAirportID IN (
    SELECT AirportID FROM airport WHERE AirportDescription LIKE '%AK%'
) AND OrigAirportID IN (
    SELECT AirportID FROM airport WHERE AirportDescription LIKE '%AK%'
);
```

One thing to remember, however, is that MySql is (usually) not case-sensitive. This means that if the string 'ak' appears *anywhere* in the Description field, it will match the WHERE clause. While 'ak' isn't too common, this is something that could provide significant problems down the road (DE, AR, CA, OR, etc.) would be better served having a dedicated 'state' column in the Airport table. SO a better query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM flight
INNER JOIN airport Orig 
 ON flight.OriginAirportID = Orig.AirportID
INNER JOIN airport Dest
 ON flight.DestAirportID = Dest.AirportID 
WHERE Orig.AirportState = 'AK' 
AND Dest.AirportState = 'AK'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you simply need to join to airport twice...

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FlightNum, F.OriginAirportID, F.DestAirportID, Dest.*, Orig.*
FROM flight F
INNER JOIN airport Dest
 ON Dest.AirportID = F.DestAirportID 
INNER JOIN airport Orig
 ON orig.AirportID = F.OriginAirportID
WHERE (Dest.AirportDescription LIKE BINARY '%AK%' 
    AND Orig.AirportDescription LIKEBINARY '%AK%')
```

Based on comments: OP is asking for all flights originating and having a destination in Alaska.

Given this understanding I believe what is needed is an AND instead of an or in the where clause and I believe I was wrong on F.Airport as pointed out in a comment.  both of these adjustments have been corrected.  Now since "STATE" is tracked in AirportDescription anything containing AK in both origin and destination will be returned.

Comment: I believe you will need `F.DestAirportID = Dest.AirportID` and `F.OriginAirportID = Orig.AirportID` instead, and you need an `AND` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jagga updated to reflect aleatoric comment above and your comment in main area.